# Find clusters of neighbours with specific total sum of nodes' attribute values

Tags: r, igraph, graph-algorithm

Consider this problem:

A country (**AMD0**) is divided into a number of administrative units, **ADM1<sub>i</sub>**, with i=1 for n=34. For each **ADM1<sub>i</sub>**, I know its population **POPADM<sub>i</sub>**.

Now, I want to find 4 clusters of neighbouring units such that the total population of the cluster equals **POPCLU<sub>j</sub>**, with j=1 for n=4.

The algorithm could return multiple outputs compatible with the requirements.

Let's load **ADM1** (download from [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/AFG_adm1.rds)) and set a `population` for each feature.

```
ADM1 <- readRDS("~/Downloads/AFG_adm1.rds")

set.seed(28100)
ADM1$population <- sample(1:100, nrow(afg_sp), replace = T)
```

and let's determine the neighbouring relations

```
require(spdep)

nb <- poly2nb(ADM1, row.names = ADM1$HASC_1)
mat <- nb2mat(nb, style="B")
colnames(mat) <- rownames(mat)
```

[image]

To layout the graph, we need the centroid for each **AMD1<sub>i</sub>**.

```
centroids_df <- cbind(as.data.frame(coordinates(ADM1)), as.data.frame(ADM1[,c("HASC_1", "population")]))
```

Now we can create a graph based on `mat`, as created before:

```
require(igraph)
ADM1_g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat, mode='undirected')
V(ADM1_g)$population <- centroids_df$population[match(V(ADM1_g)$name,centroids_df$HASC_1)]
plot(ADM1_g, layout = as.matrix(centroids_df[,1:2]), vertex.label = V(ADM1_g)$population)
```

[image]

Each node label identify the population of the feature (**POPADM<sub>i</sub>**).

This is the clustering that I want to determine algorithmically

[image]

based on these input values:

1. **POPCLU<sub>1</sub>** = 460
2. **POPCLU<sub>2</sub>** = 788
3. **POPCLU<sub>3</sub>** = 208
4. **POPCLU<sub>4</sub>** = 295

**Note:** In the example, the clustering is determined by

```
set.seed(28100)
clusters <- walktrap.community(ADM1_g)
```

which gives

- `"AF.BM" "AF.DK" "AF.GZ" "AF.HM" "AF.KD" "AF.KT" "AF.PK" "AF.PT" "AF.OZ" "AF.ZB"`
- `"AF.BD" "AF.BL" "AF.KB" "AF.KP" "AF.KR" "AF.LA" "AF.LW" "AF.NG" "AF.NR" "AF.PJ" "AF.PV" "AF.TK"`
- `"AF.BG" "AF.FH" "AF.GR" "AF.HR" "AF.NM"`
- `"AF.BK" "AF.FB" "AF.JW" "AF.KZ" "AF.SM" "AF.SP"`

Comment: Brute forcing it will be bad. The number of combinations to test will be 12295049856484723945...

Comment: Is this the problem in its final form, or is this a test case for a similar but different cost function? The fact that you want an exact solution is what makes this problem particularly hard to tackle in a computationally efficient manner.

Comment: Also, the question is very much out of scope for SO (I don't mind, though ;-)). You might find more qualified help on the stackexchange for computer science.